# Network Connect 2 virtual machines accross 2 different computers

Tags: hadoop, networking, vmware-workstation

I got an interesting idea to create a hadoop cluster by using 2 laptops connected to a router, but ran into a problem.

[image]

I am trying to network connect 2 virtual machines accross the lan using a VMware workstation as the figure above. After trying a lot i have managed to connect the hosts(the windows 10 ie), but i can't figure out how to the connect the virtual machine to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright this is how I managed to do. i left 1st system as it is, just replaced it with a ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine and a usb to ethernet adapter was added & in the vmware network adaptor was disabled & usb to ethernet adaptor was enabled.

[image]

The 2nd system was completely formated to ubuntu 16.04.

On connectinng to router everything worked Flawlessly with correct ip

Answer (score 0):

Change the network adapter to `Bridged adapter`, then only it will be accessible to outside of the VMware host.

Try above and let me if you output